# Native CURRENT_DATE() Function returning wrong date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using the native function of:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE()
```

Will return the date of yesterday. This is causing a lot of downstream issues as it is a native function called in many tasks and procedures. I can confirm that this didn't happen as of last week. I can also confirm that our snowflake parameter is set to Pacific Time. So our timezone should not be causing this.

As I cannot change this function and I don't see an obvious session parameter that would cause it. Where can I start looking?

Comment: If you can still duplicate the issue, I would suggest reaching out to support.

Comment: current_date() will return the date based on whatever your account, user, or session have their TIMEZONE parameter set to.  When are your processes running and what is the user's TIMEZONE parameter set to?  You can run `SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'TIMEZONE';` to see the active parameter value for a given user/session.  Maybe add that to a few of your procedures and log the output to verify.  If that still doesn't expose an issue, I'd contact support, as well.